# System.Double type in Windows.Foundation.Size.Width / .Height on WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a problem with the assignment of a value of `double` type on WinRT.

The following code:

```
Windows.Foundation.Size size = new Windows.Foundation.Size();
double v = 179.166660308838;
double v2 = v;
size.Width = v;
string t = $"v: {v}, v2: {v2}, size.Width: {size.Width}";
```

returns `v: 179.166660308838, v2: 179.166660308838, size.Width: 179.166656494141`. As you can see the values of `v2` and `size.Width` are different.

My questions are:

- Why is that?
- How to make it work as expected in case I have to store a value in Windows.Foundation.Size (for example in `MeasureOverride`/`ArrangeOverride`)?

Comment: The underlying storage type for Size's properties is *float*, not *double*.  A float can only round-trip 6 significant digits, if you display more of them then you'll see random noise digits.

Comment: @HansPassant I see, but why is it declared as `System.Double`?

Comment: It is not, it just has a constructor that takes doubles.

Comment: I can see the following declaration: `public System.Double Width { get; set; }`

Comment: It is part of the language projection, the MSDN article makes no bones about it actually being System.Single.  The result you see is also rather convincing I hope :)

Comment: @HansPassant where is this fact documented? Are you sure the underlying type is float and not double?

Comment: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.size.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) says "Data type: System.Single [.NET]" There's also a discussion of projection (namely, that the struct members project as properties rather than fields).

Comment: @HansPassant Any idea why it is not declared as `float`? It causes difficult to debug errors.

Comment: Representing interop types as a different native type is a core feature of the language projection.   It is more blatantly *float* in the Javascript and C++ projection.  I suspect that WPF played a key role in the choice, being first to introduce XAML and representing sizes and coordinates as *double*.  Not sure, you'd have to ask the designers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was mentioned by Hans Passant in comments "The underlying storage type for Size's properties is float, not double. A float can only round-trip 6 significant digits, if you display more of them then you'll see random noise digits."
([Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.size.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1))

You can check it using reflection:

```
        var sizeFields = typeof(Windows.Foundation.Size).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(f => $"{f.Name} - {f.FieldType.Name}");
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", sizeFields));
```

And in output you will see `_width - Single, _height - Single`

If you disassemble System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll you will see this code in constructor:

```
public Size(double width, double height)
{
  if (width < 0.0)
    throw new ArgumentException("width");
  if (height < 0.0)
    throw new ArgumentException("height");
  this._width = (float) width;
  this._height = (float) height;
}
```

Comment: Source is available here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime/src/System/Windows/Size.cs